# Symfony2: How to handle PHP Unit bootstrap file for contributed bundle?

Tags: symfony, testing, phpunit, composer-php

**What do I use as the autoload file for my PHP Unit configuration file for my contributed bundle?**

I'm writing unit tests for my first contributed Symfony 2 bundle. I'm not sure how to handle the XML configuration file `phpunit.xml.dist` for PHP Unit. I know I should write my own config file(instead of relying on the one provided by Symfony Framework), but I've seen a few different ways people handle the bootstrap file that the config uses.

Symfony framework apps have a PHP Unit config file in the `app/` folder and it uses `bootstrap.php.cache` as the autoloader, which really just defers to the composer autoloader in the vendor directory.

Several bundles I've looked at have their own bootstrap file but try and locate some other autoload file on the filesystem, making assumptions about where it may be. That doesn't seem right to me, but perhaps it is?

The [best practices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html#tests) don't get into specifics here.

Answer (score 0):

Best practices for unit testing is to test a small unit of functionality at a time, this unit should not rely on external influences and doesn't make sense to use `bootstrap.php.cache` as that is intended to bootstrap the entire symfony framework.

Your tests within a bundle should be able to execute on their own if someone were to checkout your bundle and contribute to it, they should be able to run tests there with only your code and dependencies. An ideal scenario would be that no bootstrap is necessary to set up the test suite, all you need is the autoloader.  This is why many bundles have a bootstrap script that loads the autoloader.

There are two scenarios on the autoloader location relative to the bundle, either your bundle is installed standalone and it will be in `vendor/autoload.php` or your bundle is installed as a dependency, which in a standard configuration would you would fall back to a project autoloader if that exists.

This is variable depending on your setup and usage of target dir... You would need to traverse upward at least two levels to account for vendor name and package name, then if you have a target directory configuration you would need to traverse upwards the number of directories in your target path.